# How to get UTF8 from a hex variable?

Tags: ubuntu, character-encoding

I'm debugging an app for a client and I found the information from the DB which could be solution. I ask the client to extract it but unfortunately the client sent me the raw data in hexadecimal...

I ask the client to resend me the plain text from the DB tools but awaiting their response I'm looking for a bash solution.

I know the encoded data is a UTF-8 encoded string: is there a way to decode it with Unix tools?

Comment: "The data below" is missing.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sure I forgot to remove it because I can't post here the hexa, it could be critical data as long as I didin't decode it

Comment: What is "an hexa variable"? Can you be more specific about the data's representation? Do you mean an ASCII string consisting of concatenated hex pairs? Or something else?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes I got hex pairs like `426f756e64617279496d706f736974696f6e`.

Comment: @Fractaliste: These details belong in the question please. Always when asking a question about data you should precisely define the data's format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `xxd` (usually shipped with `vim`)

```
$ echo 5374c3a97068616e650a | xxd -p -r
Stéphane
```

If your locale's charset (see output of `locale charmap`) is not UTF-8 (but can represent all the characters in the encoded string), add a `| iconv -f UTF-8`.

If it cannot represent all the characters, you could try  `| iconv -f UTF-8 -t //TRANSLIT` to get an approximation.

Comment: note for casual readers: `//TRANSLIT` is not a comment describing `-t`, it is an argument given to it ... see https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv#dealing-with-untranslatable-characters or better, see the upstream manual for the unix version : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html

Comment: This was also useful for converting html encoded utf-8 hex to characters, e.g. `echo "%F0%9F%84%B5" | tr -d '%' | xxd -p -r` by simply removing the % signs and passing to xxd.

Answer (score 3):

Does Perl count?

```
$ echo "68656c6c6f0a" | \
  perl -ne 'tr/a-fA-F0-9//cd; print pack("H*", $_)'
hello
```

If not, then maybe this might do:

```
$ echo "68656c6c6f0a" | sed -Ee 's/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/\\\\x&/g' | xargs printf 
hello
```

We need a literal backslash for `printf`, but it's special for both `xargs` and `sed` so needs to be doubled twice. (`\\\\x` -> `\\x` -> `\x`)

Comment: I can't use PERL but the sed solution works fine. Why do one's need to escape four times the `x` character?

Comment: @Fractaliste, for xargs and sed, edited